# Is there a logic game engine to be used in OS game?

Tags: logic

[Ludocore](http://www.kmjn.org/papers/Smith_etal_ludocore_2010.pdf) is a paper where a research on a logic game engine is presented.

For game I cooperate on -- Opendungeons -- it would seem fine to have separate abstract layer of code which would deal only with the logic/rules side of the game ( as there are very few now hardcoded in c++ source).

In the big picture in this system you have events, states and consequences. By custom the usage is like:

- States are somehow mapped to actual game objects ( or simplier they can be actual states of real game objects )
- Events are thrown by code side
- Consequences are thrown by events and they modify the states depending on event context.

The actual question: Is there existing software to be used in GPL project? And if not what would be simplest approach using c++ in implementing Ludlum-like system? Using common libraries?

I count this as scripting question as well, because events/state/consequences should be mostly specified in external files to source code.

Comment: That spacing...

Comment: Are you programming a game programmer?